# Custom permalink structure for multiple custom post_type URLs using add_permastruct returning regular posts error / 404

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

In my WP v6.1, I have two custom port types: `company`, `product` and custom taxonomy `country`.

Desired URL structure is `%country%/%company_postname%` and `%country%/%product_postname%` respectively and below is the code for `$wp_rewrite`:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_init');

function custom_init() {

global $wp_rewrite;
$company_url = '/%country%/%company_postname%';
$product_url = '/%country%/%product_postname%';

$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('company', $company_url, false);
$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('product', $product_url, false);

$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%company_postname%", '([^/]+)', "company=");
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%product_postname%", '([^/]+)', "product=");
}
```

With above code and another `post_type_link` filter function, I am able to generate my custom URLs. However the issue is regular `post` and `page` posts are not found returning `error_404`.

Regular post / page standard URL structure: `www.example.com/%postname%`

Have tried `add_permastruct` for posts & pages, but that did not worked. How do I show pages and posts while having the custom URLs for my custom posts.

**Update 1**
Custom posts and taxonomies were created by code.

Example of `company` code

```
function company_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Company', 'Post Type General Name', 'text'),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields'),
        'taxonomies' => array('country'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => false
    );
    register_post_type('company', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'company_post_type', 0);
```

**Update 2**

And my `post_type_link` function is:

```
function post_type_link_function($url, $post) {

    // only if post is published
    if ('' != $url && !in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft'))) {

        // get country terms
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'country');

        // country
        if (strpos($url, '%country%') !== FALSE) {
            if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) {
                $country = urlencode($terms[0]->slug);
                $url = str_replace('%country%', $country, $url);
            }
        }

        // post names
        $postnames = array('%company_postname%', '%product_postname%', '%postname%');
        foreach ($postnames as $postname) {
            $postname = $post->post_name;
            $url = str_replace($postnames, $postname, $url);
        }

        return $url;
    }

    return $url;
}
```

**Update 3**

When permalinks set to Plain `www.example.com/?p=123`, all posts, pages and custom posts are loading fine.

**Update 4**

I have observed that posts and pages are not using either `single.php` or `page.php` template. It is using `index.php`.
Whereas, I have not attached any templates to these pages or posts.

**Update 5 - resolved**

It was due the `'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/', 'with_front' => FALSE)` in the `country` custom taxonomy.
Without this `rewrite` now the pages and posts are fine.

Comment: how did you create custom post[company, product]  (via plugin or your own code) ?

Comment: By own code, see my updated question please.

Comment: And what is your "another post_type_link filter function" ?

Comment: `post_type_link` function update in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`post_type_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/) hook.

Add your custom post type and taxonomy with your custom rewrite:

```
function company_post_type() {
    
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Company', 'Post Type General Name', 'text'),
    );
    
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields'),
        'taxonomies' => array('country'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '%country%', 'with_front' => false ),
    );
    
    register_post_type('company', $args);
    
    
    $tax_args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'show_in_rest'      => true,
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'country', 'company', $tax_args );

}
    
add_action('init', 'company_post_type', 0);
```

then we run a replace on the permalink via the hook:

```
function replace_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);
    $post_type = get_post_type( $id );
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post_type == 'company'){
        
        $cat = 'country';
        
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $cat );
        if( $terms && !is_wp_error($terms) ){
            return str_replace( '%country%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;  
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'replace_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

**UPDATE:**

There seems to be a quirk with wordpress when using this syntax for your rewrite so you will need to preface the term with a front.

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'country/%country%', 'with_front' => false )
```

and in the replace post link:

```
return str_replace( 'country/%country%', $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
```

Then your URL will be:

```
country/%country%/%company_postname%
```

**make sure to flush your rewrite rules when you are done by going to: Settings > Permalinks and clicking 'save changes'**

Comment: My custom post type URLs are fine. I am having trouble with default `post` only, wanted to have the URL structure as `www.example.com/%postname%` while having the above custom URL structures for custom type posts.

Comment: Seems to be a weird quirk of wordpress. you will need to add a front to the term. Ill update my answer

Comment: With or without `'with_front' => false`, my custom post URL's are working fine. The only issue is with the default `post` posts, which returns 404 / page not found.

Comment: Correct. Read my updated answer. It’s a quirk in Wordpress. The only way around it is to add a front to the custom post type URL and the posts will work fine

Comment: That makes my custom post URLs `country/%country%/%company_postname%` instead of `/%country%/%company_postname%`, with or without `with_front`. And the posts are still 404.

Comment: When permalinks set to Plain `www.example.com/?p=123`, all posts, pages and custom posts are loading fine.

Comment: make sure the permalink settings in **Settings > Permalinks** are set to /%postname%/

Comment: Yes, it is `/%postname%/`