# How to have both custom taxonomy permalink and posts permalink reside in the root of Wordpress URL

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks, custom-taxonomy, wp-rewrite

I my WordPress v6.1, I have a custom taxonomy `country` and regular `posts` and `pages`.

With `'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/', 'with_front' => FALSE)`, I am getting my taxonomy terms URL as `www.example.com/taxonomy-term-name`. This is good.

But with the above, my regular posts and pages are returning error / 404. My desired posts and pages URLs are `www.example.com/contact` and `www.example.com/my-blog-post`.

I have tried `register_taxonomy_args` and `term_link` filters, but all fails the posts and pages URLs into 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't defining anything with `'slug' => '/'` essentially this is defaulting to your post type rewrite rule:

With that said: like i've answered you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74369832/custom-permalink-structure-for-multiple-custom-post-type-urls-using-add-permastr/74763390#74763390):

There seems to be a quirk with wordpress when using this syntax for your rewrite so you will need to preface the term with a front.

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'country/%country%', 'with_front' => false )
```

and then use `return str_replace( 'country/%country%', $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );` in the `post_type_link` hook.